# Image url from a string property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a React component and this component needs to show an `img` but the url comes from a property:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class ShowImage extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        The url is {this.props.imgUrl}.
        <img src={this.props.imgUrl} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `this.props.imgUrl` contains proper value because if I remove the line with `img` then my application shows the value properly.

This is my main application:

```
export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <ShowImage imgUrl='apple.gif' />
    )
  }
}
```

The image is not appear in the web browser because its url is not translated by `yarn build`.

I tried to use `src={require(this.props.imgUrl)}` but in this case my React app does not work.

The `apple.gif` is located in the same folder then the `*.js` files.

Is there any way to show image from string SRC parameter somehow?

Comment: try this: `imgUrl='./apple.gif'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images won't load unless you explicitly serve the static files. If you are using webpack, you can add the following code to webpack to make it serve static files.

in the webpack loaders, add

```
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=25000'
    }
```

this will make webpack load the images and the image URL will be './apple.gif' . apple.gif should be located at the root of the directory.